# Based on a Href Value Highlight Row Matching ID from Href Link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically when a user clicks on a specific link that I have set-up within an SVG graph view on a page, using a click event that calls `window.location.href` I would like it to branch to a report (html table via anchor tag) that is below the graph and highlight the rows red, matching the rule id, say where **rule id equals 90**, passed as part of the href link.

I would like to see in my example below, rows 1 and 4 highlighted red to notify the user which rules are affected.

I would also like a means of first resetting the table highlights, just in case they exists from a previous click based on a different rule id href click.

I realise that I will need to use a jQuery `.each()` function, but just not sure how to check for Rule = 90 and highlight that entire row.

HTML table may look like the following:

```
<table class="rule-table" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Rule</th>  
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="the-rule">90</td>  
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="the-rule">87</td>  
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="the-rule">22</td>    
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>        
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="the-rule">90</td>    
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `.css()`, on the filtered rows. Use jQuery filters like `contains()` no need of `.each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** jQuery selector to filter elements and `.css()` to set the values. `.closest('tr')` will get the parent row.

```
var hrefValue = 90;
$('td.the-rule:contains('+hrefValue+')').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
```

*<sub>Note : `:contains()` finds match in the whole text node.</sub>

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var hrefValue = 90;
   $('td.the-rule:contains('+hrefValue+')').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <table class="rule-table" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Rule</th>  
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="the-rule">90</td>  
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="the-rule">87</td>  
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="the-rule">22</td>    
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>        
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="the-rule">90</td>    
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.filter` and return elements containing `roleId`.

```
var ruleId = 90;
$ruleTd = $('.the-rule');
$('.rule-table tr').css('background-color', 'white');
$ruleTd.filter(function(td){
    return parseInt($(this).text()) === ruleId;
}).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var ruleId = 90;
   $ruleTd = $('.the-rule');
   $('.rule-table tr').css('background-color', 'white');
   $ruleTd.filter(function(){
       return parseInt($(this).text()) === ruleId;
   }).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <table class="rule-table" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Rule</th>  
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="the-rule">90</td>  
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="the-rule">87</td>  
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="the-rule">22</td>    
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>        
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td class="the-rule">90</td>    
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Prs Had a quick look and actually need the whole row highlighted where rule = 90, not just the rule cell - is this possible? If additional classes are needed, pls let me know and I can add them to my code.

Comment: @tonyf no addtional class needed i'hv just added a line $('.rule-table tr').css('background-color', 'white');